# file i/o and the the meaning of binary modes

Tags: python, file, io, binary

so I want to save some arbitrary piece of data in redis with python. Since redis supports this by just storing it as a string I thought I could read the date with python again and write it to a file. At first this didn`t work because I used the standard 'r' and 'w' mode of open().
Python does say they are equal though.

After I changed it to 'rb' and 'wb' it works, but why does the non binary read or write change the data somehow? what is the significance of it anyway?

here is some code which works, but just change the file modes to non-binary and watch the testfile_read.zip change. You do need redis though, easy to install with pip install redis

```
import redis
import os.path

version=1.0
path='testfile.zip'

r_server=redis.Redis("127.0.0.1")
fp = open(path,'rb')

test=fp.read()
fp.close()

r_server.hset('testfile',version,test)
r_server.hset('testfile','currver',version)


test2=r_server.hget('testfile',version)

if test==test2:
    print "read from file and read from redis are the same"
else:
    print "read from file and read from redis are the NOT!! same"

fp2 = open("testfile_read.zip",'wb')
fp2.write(test2)
fp2.close()

fp3 = open("testfile_read.zip",'rb')
test3=fp3.read()
fp3.close()

if test2==test3:
    print "redis is equal to written file"
else:
    print "redis is NOT!!! equal to written file"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-binary mode is used to have the system do some additional work for you:

Some specific examples:

- when reading text that have a different line-ending style (crlf vs cr vs lf).  For example when reading a unix style file on Windows.
- the `\n` charater will be converted to `\r\n` on windows.
- when reading input the various options (`\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`) will be converted to the correct set.
- If the file is opened in append mode, and there is an End-Of-File mark (C-z) 
  If the file is opened in append mode, the end of the file will be examined it will be removed.

Comment: I understand that now, however my code will produce a different file in non-binary mode

Comment: @prgmjunkie: yes, and you want this behaviour usually unless you are writing a special format file.

Comment: I am writing a standard file but is no text-file. I understand that I need binary but I just didn`t know why, now I do!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having non-binary mode is to have the file calls do some manipulation of the data for you (for example, translating line-endings).  That's why you don't have to worry so much about where a text file came from; the file routines hide those details from you.

Comment: do you mean the difference between unix and windows for instance? does python actually change the newlines while reading in non-binary mode?